# Order was generated without adding shipping amount

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.9

Recently I faced an very random issue about generating order without adding shipping cost. My client reported me that customer was able to complete the order without paying for shipping amount.

After reporting this issue, First of all I revised all of the error/debug log files [ system, exception, authorizedCIM, usps ] for further information about this issue but I didn't found any informative details from this files. Then after I checked the database entries of affected order and found  that shipping method entry already available in *quote* table. But for some reason sales_quote data doesn't converted to *sales_order* data.

This means shipping rates was already assigned when customer was placing order but after place order shipping data doesn't inserted to order table. Please find below screen shot of affected order database entries for your ref.

***Sales_Flat_Order* Table**
[image]

***Sales_Flat_Quote* Table**
[image]

***Sales_Flat_Quote_Shipping_Rate* Table**
[image]

***Admin Order View Page***
[image]

Please help to find out the issue or if some one have any solution for this.

Thanks in advance!